# A doubt regarding formal logic in set theory and symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C$ be subsets of an universal set and $A\Delta B=C$. I have proved $A=B\Delta C$ and $B=C\Delta A$, where $\Delta$ stands for the symmetric difference. How to prove that $$A\bigcap \left(B \bigcup  C\right)=A$$ ? My logic is as follows with which I am not satisfied with :-- if$$ x\epsilon  (A\Delta C) \bigcup (A \Delta B )$$ then x belongs to $A\Delta C$ or $A\Delta B \implies x$ belongs to A or C BUT not both OR $x$ belongs to $A$ or $B$ BUT not both, which forces( here lies my unsatisfaction) us to conclude that $x$ can belong only to $A$ and not $B$ or $C$, hence they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the symmetric difference in terms of intersection and union:

$$A \Delta B = (A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B)$$

So given:

$$C = A \Delta B$$

We find that:

$$A \cap (B \cup C) = \text{ (given)}$$

$$A \cap (B \cup (A \Delta B)) =\text{ (rewrite } \Delta)$$

$$A \cap (B \cup (A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B)) = \text{ (Reduction)}$$

$$A \cap (B \cup A \cup (A^C \cap B)) = \text{ (Absorption)}$$

$$A$$

If that went a bit quick for you:

**Reduction**

$A \cup (A^C \cap B) = A \cup B$  (in the presence of $A$, the $A^C \cap B$ term 'reduces to just $B$)

Proof:

$A \cup (A^C \cap B)= \text{ (Distribution})$

$(A \cup A^C) \cap (A \cup B)= \text{ (Complement})$

$U \cap (A \cup B)= \text{ (Identity})$

$A \cup B$

**Absorption**

$A \cap (A \cup B) = A$ (the $A$ term 'absorbs the $A \cup B$ term)

Proof:

$A \cap (A \cup B) = \text{ (Identity)}$

$(A \cup \emptyset) \cap (A \cup B) = \text{ (Identity)}$

$A \cup (\emptyset \cap  B) = \text{ (Annihilation)}$

$A \cup \emptyset  = \text{ (Identity)}$

$A$

Answer (score 1):

Using what you've already shown, $A \cap (B \cup C)$ equals $A \cap ((A ~\triangle~ C) \cup C)$. Let's show that this set equals $A$:

1. Proving $A \cap ((A ~\triangle~ C) \cup C) \subseteq A$ is trivial.
2. Let's prove that $A \subseteq A \cap ((A ~\triangle~ C) \cup C)$. We need to show that if $x \in A$, then $x \in ((A ~\triangle~ C) \cup C)$ as well. There are two cases:

   1. If $x \in C$, then $x \in ((A ~\triangle~ C) \cup C)$ also (property of $\cup$)
   2. If $x \notin C$, then $x \in (A ~\triangle~ C)$ (can you see why?), so $x \in ((A ~\triangle~ C) \cup C)$ also.

Comment: Nice argument. Thanks for the help!

Comment: By Venn diagram, x belongs to (A∆C)UC implies x belongs to A or C but not both implies x belongs to (AUC)-(A Intersection C) ?